# Android app 800x480 appears BLURRY on Tablet, but ok on Nexus One and Emulator

Tags: button, user-interface, resolution, tablet, blurry

I'm programming an app for a friend, so far it just consists of some standard buttons (ones from the UI templates). I'm using 4.0.3 API 15 ICS. When I debug with the target tablet the app title and the buttons are dithered and washed out. Like it's the wrong resolution. Everything is set to 800x480 which is the resolution of the tablet.

When I run it in the emulator it's fine. Also when I debug with a Nexus One of the same resolution it is also fine and sharp.

Does anyone know why it's blurry on the Tablet? Thanks